# Why does Google preview gives "preview not available" for site (even though magnifying glass is shown)?

Tags: google

Is there a way to debug this?

[image]

UPDATE: it just started working.

Comment: Do you see the preview of other websites? I just tested it myself using the query in the screenshot above and it worked just fine for me.

Comment: I got a really nice preview of the pages on my "personal page", it looked great, with the images in the right place etc. I can't believe stackoverflow hasn't got that yet, since they must have about a million billion times more traffic than that site does.

Comment: It even runs the JavaScript on my page.

Comment: but then how long will it take for the on-the-fly process to be complete?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It probably means that they haven't had a chance to make a preview image yet. I would guess that Googlebot and the image generator are separate processes and have different sets of priorities and queues. I wouldn't worry too much about it. Wait a week or two and if it's still the case, it might be worth posting a question on Google's forums.

Comment: Google creates previews from normal crawling as well as from on-the-fly accessing. If a preview is not cached, we'll try to create it on the fly. If that's not possible within a reasonable time, you'll see "Preview not available." As soon as the on-the-fly processing is complete, it'll show the normal preview.